# Error Visual Studio "Could not locate Java 6 or 7 SDK"

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Holas a todos,

Tengo un error al compilar mi solución de proyecto Xamarin Forms, me sale el siguiente error

```
Gravedad    Código  Descripción Proyecto    Archivo Línea   Estado de supresión
Error       Could not locate Java 6 or 7 SDK.  (Download from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads.) SISLibreta.Droid
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

También agregué una Variable de entorno de esta manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya intenté instalando el Java Development a 32 y 64 bits pero aún así tengo el error, alguna sugerencia?

Comment: hmm..creo recordar que xamarin necesita java 6 o 7 de 32 bits...por lo que veo tienes instalado java 8,no es así?

Comment: @Pikoh Así es, pero ya descargué e instalé la versión 7 y la cambié en Java Development Kit Location, además agregué una variable de entorno llamada JAVA_HOME con a la misma ruta "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_80" y aún así tengo el error

Comment: Ok, es que como vi que tenías jdk1.8... y seguro que no tienes otra variable de entorno JAVA_HOME apuntando a 1.8 verdad?

Comment: @Pikoh Ya actualicé la pregunta, verifica las imágenes por favor.

Comment: ya probaste en la consola de windows ver que version te muestra intenta, es este comando java -version

Comment: @RaulCacacho Probé con el comando que dijiste y me arrojó que tenía la versión 1.8 a 64 bits, así que procedí a desinstalar esta versión de Java, y reinstalar la versión 1.7 a 32 bits, ejecuté el comando de nuevo y me decía que no era un comando válido,así que reinicié el equipo y aparecia lo mismo, luego instalé la versión 1.7 a 64 bits y ejecuté el comando de nuevo y ya me arrojó que tenía la versión 1.7 pero a 64 bits... y que tengo es el runtime enviroment, no el jdk

Comment: Estaba revisando en la pagina de oracle pero ya no esta disponible la versión 7 pero aqui hay un link donde puedes bajarlo es el 32 bits https://java-7-jdk.waxoo.com/descargar prueba nos contas

Comment: @RaulCacacho Bueno, pues me apareció una actualización para Xamarin forms, así que la instalé y se solucionó ese problema. Ahora funciona con la versión 1.8 a 64 bits perfectamente, muchas gracias por la ayuda!